# C#: How do you make sure that a row or item is selected in ListView before performing an action?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

What is the best way to check if there is atleast a selected item in a listview or not in an if statement?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you are asking.  Do you want to make sure at least 1 item is selected before running an action?  If so the following should work

```
if ( listView.SelectedItems.Count > 0 ) { 
  // Do something
}
```

Or are you curious if a particular item is selected?  If so try the following

```
if ( listView.SelectedItems.Contains(someItem)) { 
  // Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if( listView.SelectedItems.Count > 0 ){
 // do stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also check the value of a selected item or perhaps bind it to a string if needed:

```
        //Below is with string
        String member = (String)ListView1.SelectedValue;

        //Below is with any class
        AnyClass member = (AnyClass)ListView1.SelectedValue;
        String StaffID = member.StaffID;
```

Answer (score 0):

int taskId = Convert.ToInt32(itemRow.SubItems[0].Text);

string taskDate = itemRow.SubItems[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqiTm.png).ToString();

string taskDescription = itemRow.SubItems[2].ToString();[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DqiTm.png)

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Can you elaborate more on your answer?

Answer (score -1):

```
//Here a simple loop that go through all the items in the list  

for (int i = 0; i < listView1.Items.Count; i++)
{
    //checks if the item in the list has the value true to the properties checked 

    if (listView1.Items[x].Checked == true)
    {//your  code
        //e.g. 
        listView1.Items[x].Checked = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can also check count of the selected item list by using getCheckedItemCount() method of the listview. for example,

if( listview.getCheckedItemCount() > 0 ) {

```
 // do stuff here
```

}